# How to recreate views released when memory warning is received

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory

If an application receives a low memory warning and a view controller releases the view, how does one reload the view the next time it's needed. I have my views defined in a .xib file and on earlier iphones, the views are being set to nil. Where/when/how do I recreate these views if they are removed?

Comment: It should work magically, didn't it? How did you create your view controller?

Comment: Using initWithNibName and a .xib file.

Comment: Should I not set the stuff defined in the nib to nil when I get a memory warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was writing my code pretty much horribly wrong. I was setting views to nil in viewDidUnload but all my creation was done in init. So when the application received a memory warning, when I went back to that view controller, the views were gone. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261972/what-exactly-must-i-do-in-viewdidunload/2262005#2262005) helped me realize my mistake; namely, that additional views could be added to viewDidLoad so that if they are released due to memory warnings in viewDidUnload, they can be recreated.