# Which method should use to release an object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I found that the iphone have viewDidUnload, and dealloc. I want to release the object. Which method should I use to release the object? What's the different between them?

Comment: I don't know Objective-C or iPhone development, but viewDidUnload does not sound like a method that is used to release an object.

Answer (score 7):

Send `release` or `autorelease` to release an object. You shouldn't send `dealloc`; the Obj-C runtime will do that.

If you're asking *where* you should release an owned object, read: "[When should I release objects in -(void)viewDidUnload rather than in -dealloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158788/when-should-i-release-objects-in-voidviewdidunload-rather-than-in-dealloc)"

Answer (score 0):

Do not call `dealloc`. Use the retain-release model for memory management, and Objective-C will take care of deallocating memory for you.

See [this link](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) for a good explanation of how retain-release works.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that `viewDidUnload` is used to release "spare" objects in low memory situations while `dealloc` is used to release all objects when the view is no longer needed.

This means that you will almost always have a `dealloc` method but have a `viewDidUnload` method only where it makes sense.