# Release any retained subviews of the main view on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I saw this code in the project template and a few other sample projects.

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}
```

Can someone explain to me what self.myOutlet = nil does? Does it release the memory? I thought you put [myOutlet release] in - (void)dealloc to release the memory. what is = nil? and when do you need to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `myOutlet` is specified as a `@property (retain)` then whenever you assign it to point to a new object, the old one will be released and the new one retained. When you assign it to `nil`, that therefore releases the object that it previously pointed to.

Comment: if myOutlet was a UIButton with @property (retain, nonatomic) then I have to set it to nil in viewDidUnload and [myOutlet release] in dealloc?

Comment: @Fasid: No, just do one of those two things, not both.

Comment: not true - you still must release outlets in dealloc method. Quote from docs: "If your view controller stores references to views and other custom objects, it is also responsible for relinquishing ownership of those objects safely in its dealloc method."

Answer (score 2):

Typically `viewDidUnload` method is called when low memory warning occurred and controller's view gets unloaded (controller itself stays in memory). As David pointed in his answer usually outlets are being retained by controller so they stay in memory even after the main view is gone - that reduces the benefits of unloading the view.

You still need to release you outlets in dealloc method even if you release them in `viewDidUnload`

For more details see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158788/when-should-i-release-objects-in-voidviewdidunload-rather-than-in-dealloc)