# why do I see some code where stuff is released in viewDidUnload as opposed to dealloc?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management

All the tutorials I have done say that I set stuff to nil in viewDidUnload and then release in dealloc. However I am being told that this would cause a memory leak since viewDidUnload gets called before a dealloc and so I am unable to release anything that is set to nil.

Can someone help clarify?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should I release objects in -(void)viewDidUnload rather than in -dealloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158788/when-should-i-release-objects-in-voidviewdidunload-rather-than-in-dealloc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create an object (with `alloc` and `init`) in `viewDidLoad`, then you should `release` it in `viewDidUnload`. The reason is that sometimes `viewDidUnload` is called to save memory, but `dealloc` is not called. Then, later, `viewDidLoad` may be called again. In general, release anything you allocate in the inverse method, e.g.

If you allocate an object in `init`, then release it in `dealloc`.

If you allocate an object in `viewDidLoad`, then release it in `viewDidUnload`.

If you allocate an object in `viewWillAppear` (or `viewDidAppear`), then release it in `viewWillDisappear` (or `viewDidDisppear`).

Comment: what about iboutlets or properties? any special rules?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the answer given by [@Sean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/66662/sean-murphy) in this previous [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158788/when-should-i-release-objects-in-voidviewdidunload-rather-than-in-dealloc). He clearly states the purpose of releasing in `viewDidUnload`

> One of the most important reasons for
>   implementing it is that
>   UIViewController subclasses commonly
>   also contain owning references to
>   various subviews in the view
>   hierarchy. These properties could have
>   been set through IBOutlets when
>   loading from a nib, or
>   programmatically inside -loadView, for
>   instance.
>
> The additional ownership of subviews
>   by the UIViewController means that
>   even when its view is removed from the
>   view hierarchy and released to save
>   memory, through which the subviews are
>   also released by the view, they will
>   not actually be deallocated because
>   the UIViewController itself still
>   contains its own outstanding retaining
>   references to those objects as well.
>   Releasing the UIViewController's
>   additional ownership of these objects
>   ensures they will be deallocated as
>   well to free memory.
>
> The objects that you release here are
>   usually recreated and set again when
>   the UIViewController's view is
>   re-loaded, either from a Nib or
>   through an implementation of
>   -loadView.
>
> Also note that the UIViewController's
>   view property is nil by the time this
>   method is called.