# ViewController viewDidLoad after presentModalView called?

Tags: ios, viewdidload, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a viewController called "FirstViewController". In an IBAction i call another ViewController called "thePageFlipViewController" and push it in sight via

`[self presentModalViewController:thePageFlipViewController animated:YES];`

after some time the user closes thePageFlipViewController with a button where the following code is executed via a delegate in FirstViewController:

`[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`
`[thePageFlipViewController release];`

And here is my problem:

`-viewDidLoad`in FirstViewController get's sometimes called after dismissing `thePageFlipController`. I don't understand why, because `firstViewController` should live in background. Is it dependent how long the modal view is displayed? is it possible that ARC does release something?

My problem is, that i initialise a lot of objects in viewDidLoad and the app crashes if `viewDidLoad` gets called again. I define some Routes for RESTKit there and RestKit complains that the routes are already set up and crash the app.

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you implementing viewDidUnload as well? (if not, you should)

Comment: That's what i need to do now! Hoped the View wouldn't be released in background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a view is not actually displayed it can be unloaded to free up memory.  You would get a call to `viewDidUnload:` when that happens so you can release any objects you are holding strong references to.   Then next time the view is needed, `viewDidLoad:` will get called again when the view is reloaded, there you have to recreate the objects you released in `viewDidUnload:`.

See the [Memory Management section](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW56) of the UIViewController class reference.

Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1160490/154803) has a good explanation already.

Comment: that's what i was afraid of. Thanks for the answer! I need to release all objects and re allocate them again.